# cppUnit: setUp function executed once for multiple testmethods

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cppunit

I've got an object `Obj` doing some (elaborate) computation and want to check weather the result (let's call it `aComputed` and `bComputed`) is correct or not. Therefore I want to split this task up into multiple test methods:

```
testA() { load aToBe; check if number aComputed = aToBe }
testB() { load bToBe; check if number bComputed = bToBe }
```

The problem is, that `Obj` is "executed" twice (which takes a lot of time) - one time per test. The question is: How can I manage that it's just "executed" once and the result is used used by both tests?

At the moment `Obj` is placed inside the `setUp`-function and saves the results to a private member of the test-class.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy solution that allows you to split the code into two test methods. Each test method results in a new test object with an own set of local variables.

Obviously you could work around this problem through a static variable but in the long run this normally just causes issues and breaks the ideas behind the framework.

The better idea is to just write the two CPPUNIT_ASSERT in the same test method. If the results are part of the same calculation there is most likely not much value in splitting the checks into two independent test methods.

Comment: I can create <code>Obj</code> with different parameters. If I select them carefully I get the (almost) same result. <code>TestA<code> does that, while <code>testB</code> is validating the result against values loaded from a file. It would have been great to have this in seperate tests, since the aim of the tests differs. I expected an answer like yours - this also was my conclusion after some investigation....